# How to use neo4jrestclient to make a node with properties from a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, neo4j, neo4j.py

What is the easiest/best way to get the key-value stores from my dictionary into the node properties in neo4jrestclient?

I have a dictionary

```
nodeDict = {"color":"Red", "width":16, "height":32}
```

How do I insert the dictionary into the property list during node creation?

from the neo4jrestclient doc page, the way to create a node with properties is

```
n = gdb.nodes.create(color="Red", widht=16, height=32)
```

I can iterate through the dictionary, generating a JSON request for each key-value store, but that seems wrong. 
Creating the node and assigning properties should be done with a single JSON request, right?

I could convert the dictionary to a string, strip off the curly braces, and change the colons into equal signs, but that also seems wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know neo4j API; but given what you describe, [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) should do the job:

```
n = gdb.nodes.create(**nodeDict)
```

Comment: This is the most concise solution. Additionally, if the node already exists, but you wan to update all properties based on a dict, you can use `n.properties = {'a' : 1}` [in versions > 1.7.0](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client/issues/63).

Answer (score 0):

Also, I am not sure Cypher is supported yet in Neo4jRestClient, but with that you could do like http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-create.html#create-create-single-node-from-map ,

```
create n = {props}
```

and pass in the props as a parameter.

HTH

Comment: Cypher is available as a plugin: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/6aiAsjhr9-I/kJyrrC9pUqoJ . It's possible, but ugly until the next release of neo4jrestclient

Comment: And it is part of the core REST API now, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-cypher.html